# Type Safety using Generics : Check T to Interface<T>

Tags: c#, generics

I am wondering if there is an easier way to validate that the generic type of an interface is equivalent to the parameter type passed, preferably without specifically noting the type.

I also am afraid I am over engineering my setup a bit. That may seem silly seeing as this is pretty small overall. But what I am trying to do is create some separation between a class (Test) which declares an order and format of a Transport. I want to be able to easily switch out my ITransport. I want the caller to pass the type of formatter it would like the transport to use, but the transport should get the final say whether that formatter is created/used.

```
public interface IFormatter<T>
{
    void Format(T val);
}

public interface ITransport
{
    //What I can do
    void Insert<T, T1>(T val) where T1 : IFormatter<T>, new();

    //Closer to what I want
    void Insert<T>(T1 val) where T : IFormatter<T1>, new();
}

public class NumericFormatter : IFormatter<string>, IFormatter<int>
{
    public void Format(string val){ ... }
    public void Format(int val){ ... }
}

public class TestTransport : ITransport
{
    public void Insert<T, T1>(T val) where T1 : IFormatter<T>, new() { ... }
}

public class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
        int i = 1234;
        string s = "1234"
        decimal d = 1234;

        var gw = new TestTransport();

        //What I currently can do
        gw.Insert<string, NumericFormatter>(s);
        gw.Insert<int, NumericFormatter>(i);
        gw.Insert<decimal, NumericFormatter>(d); //Illegal - Compile Error

        //What I think I want
        gw.Insert<NumericFormatter>(i);
        gw.Insert<NumericFormatter>(s);
        gw.Insert<NumericFormatter>(d); //Compile error
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

The compile errors are actually wanted. I want the system to prevent a developer from using a type with a formatter that doesn't know how to process the given type.

My Question is: Is there a way to get rid of the need to explicitly define the type in the Insert function

i.e -

```
Insert<iFormatter<T>>(T val)
```

RATHER THAN

```
Insert<T, iFormatter<T>>(T val);
```

I realize I am probably just being overly picky.

Comment: You're looking for partial type inference, which C# does not support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
public void Insert<T>(T value, IFormatter<T> instance)
```

What it does is just makes you assign a type, and when you pass the Formatter instance, it must comply with the type.

Or why don't you reverse your logic, pass the Type of your Value and you're always sure that the IFormatter is complying with the type of the value passed rather than making value comply with IFormatter

Update 1:

You can also pass a wrapped object in your parameter

```
public void Insert<T>(YourWrap<T> instance);

    public class YourWrap<T>
    {
        public IFormatter<T> Formatter { get; set; }

        public T Parameter { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I thought about doing this, but it would cause the Formatter to be created when the transport might just ignore it. i.e Insert("1234", new StringFormatter()); I am just weighing options.

Comment: @Zholen posted a different option

Answer (score 0):

if i understood you... shouldn't you replace this line:

```
public void Insert<T, T1>(T val) where T1 : IFormatter<T>, new() { ... }
```

with this:

```
public void Insert<T1>(T val) where T1 : IFormatter<T>, new() { ... }
```

Comment: This doesn't work because T is not defined ahead of time. I believe it would need to be either Insert<T, T1> or ITransport<T> to make your solution work.